# Traceback when using Pandas to convert to Json Format

Tags: python, json, pandas, nba-api

I recently have been trying to use the NBA API to pull shot chart data. I'll link the documentation for the specific function I'm using [here](https://github.com/swar/nba_api/blob/master/docs/nba_api/stats/endpoints/shotchartdetail.md).

I keep getting a traceback as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nbastatsrecieve2.py", line 27, in <module>
    df.to_excel(filename, index=False)
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2023, in to_excel
    formatter.write(
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\excel.py", line 730, in write
    writer = ExcelWriter(stringify_path(writer), engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 637, in __new__
    raise ValueError(f"No engine for filetype: '{ext}'") from err
ValueError: No engine for filetype: ''
```

This is all of the code as I currently have it:

```
from nba_api.stats.endpoints import shotchartdetail
import pandas as pd
import json

print('Player ID?')
playerid = input()
print('File Name?')
filename = input()

response = shotchartdetail.ShotChartDetail(
    team_id= 0,
    player_id= playerid
)

content = json.loads(response.get_json())

# transform contents into dataframe
results = content['resultSets'][0]
headers = results['headers']
rows = results['rowSet']
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df.columns = headers

# write to excel file
df.to_excel(filename, index=False)
```

Hoping someone can help because I'm very new to the JSON format.

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Just make sure you have the latest `openpyxl` installed. And filename should have an .xlsx extension.

Comment: @NYCCoder how should I update openpyxl, because now it's saying that the module isn't found

Comment: `pip install openpyxl --upgrade`

Comment: @NYCCoder thanks for the help! Now I need to figure out why it's only returning to me shots that were made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this because the `filename` has no extension. Pandas will use the extension (like `xlsx` or `xls`) of the filename (if you're not giving it an `ExcelWriter`) to understand the right lib to use for this format. Just try this with something like `df.to_excel('filename.xlsx', index=False)` and see how goes.

Comment: Got it work by doing: `'filename = input() + '.xlsx'`